# Classification question

Tags: frameworks

If php and ruby are languages, and cake and rails are frameworks, how do CMS like drupal and joomla fit into the scheme... can you use them in any language and any framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMS: Content Management **System**.

Hence they are systems. A system is a finished product.

The purpose of a CMS is simple: the end-user can do something with it, in this case managing content of a website.

The systems you mentioned, Drupal and Joomla, are extensible: they have an architecture that allow plugins to extend functionality. Still, they are products.

Frameworks, on the other hand, are not finished products. They do have an architecture (the framework architecture). They also allow plugins to extend functionality. The difference, however, is that a framework itself is not a product, and cannot be used by the end-user.

Comment: so in that sense would you say that any CMS could be used to extend the functionality of a framework? and if so, ANY framework or are some CMS specific to certain frameworks?

Comment: @Adam, it depends. If the product is compatible with Ruby and Rails, then yes: it is built on that framework. If it's not compatible, then no; it's not built on that framework.